# DNA find all matching items from a list in a string (python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, list, find

Hey so I have a string of letters (it's DNA) and I have a list of sliced up DNA that came from another sequence. I want to find all occurrences of any items in the list within my string.
basically:

```
data_1 = "ATGCTGCATGTCATGTGCTGATCTG"
wild_type = ["A", "TG", "ATGC", "ATG", "TGCT", "GTA", "GTACT", "GT", "CT"]
```

I want the output to be a list of indexes in data_1 where matches from wild_type were found.

Additionally, I want to find the longest piece that matches. So for the first part of the string, `A`, `ATG`, `ATGC` all match, so I don't need it to spit out `[0,1,2,3]`, but rather just `[0,3]` (a range)

I tried using finditer but i could not figure out how to put my list or string in there. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want ranges as a list of tuples? What happens in there are multiple ranges?

Comment: yes, a list of tuples. so like for "CA" there would be [6,7] and [11,12] printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your **first question**, you have to write a function which does exactly what you want, it gets two strings and then return indexes of occurence of second in first:

```
def my_find(str1,str2):
    start = 0
    end = len(str1)
    all_finds = []
    while str1.find(str2,start,end) != -1 :
        x = str1.find(str2,start,end)
        all_finds.append(x)
        start = x+1

    return all_finds
```

then check for all of wild types:

```
for item in wild_type :
    print my_find(data_1,item)
```

which results like this :

```
[0, 7, 12, 20]
[1, 4, 8, 13, 15, 18, 23]
[0]
[0, 7, 12]
[1, 15]
[]
[]
[9, 14]
[3, 17, 22]
```

if you check you see for the first one which is for "A" , it first occurs in index 0 then 7 and ....

for your **second question**,there are two ways!the first one is easier but slower,the second one is a bit harder to implement but faster!depending on your data set size, you have to choose one:

1-brute force it!:
  for all of your wild types,check it!if you can find the longest wild type in data_1 then it is the longest common string!because no string would be longer than the longest wild_type :))

```
>>> max_len = -1
>>> max_cut = [-1,-1]
>>> for item in wild_type:
    if my_find(data_1,item) and len(item) > max_len:
        max_len = len(item)
        max_cut[0] = my_find(data_1,item)[0]
        max_cut[1] = my_find(data_1,item)[0]+len(item)


>>> max_len
4
>>> max_cut
[0, 4]
>>>
```

2- search for [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) python implementation,(LCS = Longest Common Substring) :
  it uses Dynamic Programming approach and solves your problem

Comment: first of all this is a pretty much unpythonic way to go with this task, secondly OP wants the max range which your code doesn't do that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search()` to find the matches inside your string then use `span` method to get the position of the matches and store to positions in a dictionary (using [dict.setdefault method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) )with this logic that the first positions are the key and the common end positions are in a list as the values then use `max` function to find the max range :

```
>>> d={}
>>> from operator import sub
>>> for i in wild_type:
...    match=re.search('{}'.format(i),data_1)
...    if match:
...       i,j=match.span()
...       d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
>>> d
{0: [1, 4, 3], 1: [3, 5], 3: [5], 9: [11]}
>>> max(((i,j[-1]) for i,j in d.items()),key=lambda x:abs(sub(*x)))
(1, 5)
```

And if you want all the matches as you said in comment you can just do :

```
>>> [(i,j[-1]) for i,j in d.items()]
[(0, 3), (1, 5), (3, 5), (9, 11)]
```

Comment: i tried this, and it doesn't work for me. it's a bit confusing as I am a beginning programmer.

Comment: @bioinfo221 How it doesn't work? what was the problem? your task is not a simple so it's solutions wont be simple too! ;) tell that what part is vague here for you!

Comment: @bioinfo221 Since you are dealing with bioinformatic data you need to learn to use the much optimized approaches because in huge strings or other big data you will encounter with a lot of problems, if your code doesn't be optimized.